# univariate_data function does not work in python tensorflow tutorial (pandas dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to follow this tensorflow tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series

However, when I use the univariate_data function, it doesn't work. I tried this tutorial half a year ago and it did not work either.

I am using my own data, but it is prepared in the same way as the weather data in the tutorial:
[image]

The error has also occured with the regular example weather data.
This is the error I'm getting:

[image]

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

univariate_data is not one of the builtin functions of python or any of the libraries used in that tutorial.

It is a user defined function in the same document/tutorial that you are following.

Here is the code for the function (Also mentioned in the same link you posted):

```
def univariate_data(dataset, start_index, end_index, history_size, target_size):
  data = []
  labels = []

  start_index = start_index + history_size
  if end_index is None:
    end_index = len(dataset) - target_size

  for i in range(start_index, end_index):
    indices = range(i-history_size, i)
    # Reshape data from (history_size,) to (history_size, 1)
    data.append(np.reshape(dataset[indices], (history_size, 1)))
    labels.append(dataset[i+target_size])
  return np.array(data), np.array(labels)
```

Calling this function after defining in above mentioned code should solve the problem.